Is it possible to increase the height of Elops 100 steering column?
I have an Elops 100 bike from Decathlon, and I thought that perhaps it is possible to adjust the height of the steering column. I wanted to do this a few years after buying the bike, so the steering column has already become rusty. I tried loosening the steering column nut and removing the core bolt:


I also tried loosening the ring you can see in the first picture on the bottom. The nut is so damaged because I did not have the right key size and used a pipe wrench (Forgive me). I could not pull the shaft up, so I began to wonder if it even is adjustable in the first place?
It is this bike: https://fietsvergelijkers.nl/fietsen/btwin-elops-100/
Please let me know if you know if the steering column height is adjustable by default, and if it is not, are there any custom extensions I could use?
EDIT: More info, the knurled ring can also be turned, I tried loosening it to the max, it made the column loose in X-Y direction, but not Z.

Hi, welcome to bicycles.  Could you add an overall view of the head tube and stem?  It looks like a quill stem, which should be height-adjustable if it's not already at the limit, but given the rust it may be seized.

You have a quill stem.
To adjust it, back out the vertical bolt a bit (don't undo it completely)  and then tap it in lightly like a nail.  This should release the wedge and let you adjust the quill stem up and down, then retighten.  If you're lucky, try reinserting the long bolt till it catches the thread.
Do please pay attention to any "minimum insertion" marks on the stem.
This is what it should look like on the inside - your goal is to loosen and raise the wedge up the steerer tube a bit.


The munched nut is part of the "headset" and did not need adjusting.  Hopefully it still turns okay without being too tight or loose - future adjustments could be difficult !
Also - put the power tools away.  You only need hand hex drivers here - the risk of overtightening and stripping threads is high with power tools.   A 6mm hex driver should work fine on your quill stem's wedge bolt.
